# Insert Jinja2 variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2, morris.js

I'm trying to refactor my JS. I have various Morris.js functions inside a `<script>` on my html file. This html gets rendered by flask. The data from the functions is given directly from the server via Jinja2 template system.

Is there any way to have these functions in a JS file and give them the jinja values?

I really don't want to have onClick nor JS scripts in the html, I want to have all JS in separate JS files, as long as its possible. As far as I know, I can't as these variables are rendered by the engine, but in my mind, the script that imports the JS file is also rendered by the jinja engine, so I'm not really sure.

I think that passing data through the `meta` tag could be a possibility, but I really don't want any hacks, if I can't or there is not a "proper" way to do it, I won't do it.

Example function:

```
foo = function(){
        new Morris.Line({
              element: 'network-chart',
              data: [
              {% for load in node_statistics %}
                { y: {{load['time']}}000, a: {{load['b_sum_up']}}, b: {{load['b_sum_down']}}, c: {{load['b_max_up']}}, d: {{load['b_max_down']}} },

             {% endfor %}
              ],
              xkey: 'y',
              ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
              labels: ['sum up bandwidth', 'sum down bandwidth', 'max up bandwidth', 'max down bandwidth']
            });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just pass the arguments to your function if you will place your js in separate file.

Comment: That would mean passing the data through an onclick in the html, correct?

Comment: If that's the only way, I won't do it. I don't want to have JS in my html